# Uno-Platform: Default FontFamily not available for WASM deployment?

Tags: uno-platform

I have built and tested my uno-platform WASM app (yea!) and, like Android and UWP, the default FontFamily for all text is a san-serif font (I'm guessing it's Segoe UI).

I am very happy with this as a default.

Unfortunately, when I then test deploy the contents of my WASM app's `bin/Release/netstard2.0/dis` folder by using Apache on my Mac, all the text is rendered using Times New Roman (and all of the FontIcons using `SegoeMdl2` are not rendered.

EDIT: Looks like everything is fine when I view the WASM app on a PC (when served from a Mac) - so perhaps the WASM can't find the Segoe fonts?  Are additional steps required to assure the Segoe fonts are packaged with a WASM app ... or is all this because of font licensing?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, I followed [this post from Martin Zikmund](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2020/01/custom-fonts-in-uno-platform/), using Segoe fonts found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/segoe-ui).

That fixed the technical issue.

Looking at Segoe license, looks like it can get expensive quickly - which likely explains why it wasn't packaged in Uno by default.